# How to move a row from one google spreadsheet to another based on a value in a cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script is supposed to move a row from one google spreadsheet to another based on a value in a cell. It fails to do so, and I think it's because of the onEdit() function but can't figure it out. I found a solution for different sheets in the same spreadsheet but not in different spreadsheets. My code is below.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "source_sheet" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Pavlovo"){

  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getRange(1, 3, 1, 5);
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // tss = target spreadsheet 
  var tss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_t7BDCWgHJDip_cndzVashxLDQ_pVS6obi3I9TB_EJI'); 

  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Vitosha'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Move"? you want to delete from current sheet and paste it in new sheet?

Comment: Exactly. To remove it from the mother spreadsheet and add it to the new spreadsheet!

Comment: What is wrong in your attempt? If you want to remove the row from the sheet you may use: sheet.deleteRow(1)

Comment: deleting is not the problem. What Marshmallow is saying below is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using a simple trigger `onEdit`. Such triggers run without authorization and therefore are subject to several [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions), such as:

> They can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other files because that would require authorization.

This is why `SpreadsheetApp.openById` fails to execute in your code.

Solution: rename the function to something other than onEdit, and add an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) running on edits. An installable trigger runs as you (i.e., the user who created it), and therefore can access any files that you can access.

Comment: Thanks but can you share the code with an installable trigger